# Converting a variant of unique_ptr back to its original form

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, variant

I have a `std::variant` as follows:

```cpp
using DataPtr = std::variant<std::unique_ptr<F1>, std::unique_ptr<F2>>;
```

I want to convert it back to a `std::unique_ptr<F1>`. I tried to do this:

```cpp
const std::unique_ptr<F1> f1_ptr = std::get<std::unique_ptr<F1>>(std::move(dataPtr));
```

but it fails with this error:

> `error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = F1; _Dp = std::default_delete<F1>]`

The object F1 is defined as such:

struct F1 {
int x;
};

Comment: Use `std::move(std::get<std::unique_ptr<F1>>(dataPtr))`?

Comment: Side note: the same code implemented via `visitor` will look nicer.

Comment: What compiler/version are you using?  Both your form and the form suggested by NathanOliver should [produce the same valid results](https://godbolt.org/z/EoYh88x8E).

Comment: The wording `error: use of deleted function` seems to come from gcc.  I'm inclined to close as "[Not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/v96K7eeY8)"

Comment: @NathanOliver i tried that but i get the same issue

Comment: @raaj Then we need a [mre]( which you almost have).  Please include what compiler you are using and what compiler options you are using to compile with.